# robots.txt how to disallow jpg.php

Tags: apache, robots.txt

Hello after seeing a friends website hacked I am trying to disallow any file with double extension. i.e. myimage.jpg.php but allow a regular .jpg to work normally.

```
Disallow: *.* //disallow all extensions

Allow: *.jpg //now allow .jpg images
Disallow: *.jpg*?* //but not query strings

Disallow: *.php$ //now make sure .php files cant be touched
Disallow: *.*.php$ //double check jpg.php does not work <<--- this or above should work but it does not?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not robots.txt (which is entirely optional for computers/spiders to read and follow) but a law in .htaccess. If you run an Apache server then you can use htaccess files to control what you want your viewers/ users to reach.

The difference is `robots.txt` is optional for others to follow, whereas `.htaccess` is not.

try this in your .htaccess:

```
<Files ~ ".*\.[a-z0-9]{1,6}\.[a-z0-9]{1,6}$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This blocks access to any files that have double extensions, although if you're unfamiliar with it then I suggest you do some reading up on htaccess from this excellent website: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Robots.txt wont keep hackers out. A bot is not forced to read it. It is only used by nice bots.

If you want to keep nice bots out of anything but *.jpg, you can use this:

```
Disallow: *.*
Allow: *.jpg$
```

Note the `$` character at the end.

Use htaccess to setup rules for which files are accessible and how.

Comment: Well that pulled the rug from under my feet... A bot is not forced to read it I think I will ask for my Degree payment back the prof missed that one

Comment: hahaha you got a web design degree? I'm sorry but that's probably almost worthless.

Comment: I actual did this in 1999 before things too off with the internet, and it was a BA In Digital Art and Multimedia